# Program complied with no error , but does not output anything

Tags: c++

here is the code below, I am trying to convert infix expression to posfix expression. I am just trying to handle parenthesis case right now, but it does not output any thing, according to my understanding it should output correct post expr for infix3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string I2PConvertor(string exp);
string I2PConvertor(string exp)
{
    stack<int> st;
    string ans;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.size(); i++) {
        if (isalpha(exp[i])) {
            ans += exp[i];
        }
        else {
            if (st.empty()) {
                st.push(exp[i]);
            }
            else {
                switch (st.top()) {
                case '(':
                    st.push(exp[i]);
                case '+':
                    st.push(exp[i]);
                case ')': {
                    st.pop();
                    while (st.top() != '(') {
                        ans += st.top();
                        st.pop();
                    }
                    st.pop();
                    st.push(exp[i]);
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (!st.empty()) {
        ans += st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    string infix1 = "a*b+c";
    string infix2 = "a-b*c";
    string infix3 = "(a+b)/c";
    string infix4 = "(a+b)*(c-d)";
    // expected: ab*c+
    //std::cout << I2PConvertor(infix1) << std::endl;
    // expected: abc*-
    //std::cout << I2PConvertor(infix2) << std::endl;
    // expected: ab+c/
    std::cout << I2PConvertor(infix3) << std::endl;
    // expected: ab+cd-*
    // std::cout << I2PConvertor(infix4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't use any `break;` statements in a [`switch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch), the cases will fall through.

Comment: If you add a `std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;` into `main()`, does it output that?

Comment: "Program compiled with no error" - but it compiles with warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/nq8scnE1h

Comment: Probably crashing due to popping from an empty stack. The missing `breaks` are likely the key.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner no it does not.

Comment: For future reference, you can use a debugger to identify where the crash is happening. I just plugged this into gdb and it told me the error was on line 30 (the while loop), which narrowed it down quite a bit.

Comment: @sabrabaig in that case one of two things is true:  either the program's execution never reaches the "Hi there" line (infinite loop somewhere?  Try moving the "Hi there" to the top of main() and see if it prints out then), or you have some problem with your execution environment such that you are not able to see the contents of the program's stdout (Windows in particular can be quite cagey about allowing you to see stdout when a Windows program runs)

Comment: Side note: A lack of compiler errors means the program is syntactically correct. The grammar is right. Unfortunately compilers are not required to warn you if the logic expressed by the grammar is correct. Most of the time they can't because the compiler can't know what you are actually thinking. It only knows what you told it. You need different tools for that. Here is an example of using sanitizers to find bugs using Yksisarvinen's Compiler Explorer link with an extra compiler option turned on: https://godbolt.org/z/7qK198EW5

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a `case` block should, barring exceptional circumstances, be ended with a `break` statement.

```
switch (st.top()) {
case '(':
  st.push(exp[i]);
  break;
case '+':
  st.push(exp[i]);
  break;
case ')': {
  ...
  break;
}
}
```

It's also worth noting that you'll want to do some checks in your `)` case that the stack is not empty before checking the top element haphazardously. Unless this is an academic exercise and your teacher promises to *only* give valid input, there's still the risk of segfault if that case gets hit on an empty stack, so some error checking may be warranted.